# Passing parameters from method to main

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameters

I can't seem to figure out what my parameters should be for my method "public static int[][] sellSeatByPrice". I need to prompt the user for a price (of a seat), then figure out if that price is taken (if it = 0) and if not, assign it the value 0.

Below is my code, help please!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Write a description of class A10_TheaterSeating here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class A10_TheaterSeating
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println("***Welcome to the Ticket Choice App!***");
    System.out.println();

    int[][] theaterSeats = //set values in seating chart array
    {
        {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10},
        {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10},
        {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10},
        {10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10},
        {10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10},
        {10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10},
        {20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 30, 30, 20, 20},
        {20, 30, 30, 40, 50, 50, 40, 30, 30, 20},
        {30, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 40, 30}
    };
    int[][] seats = theaterSeats;

    printArray(seats); //print the seating chart
    System.out.println();

    //Defining variables
    String str = "";
    String input = "";

    while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
    {
        System.out.print("Select 'S' to pick a seat, 'P' choose a price or 'Q' to quit:     ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = in.next();

        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
        {
            System.out.print("Enter row and seat number desired: ");
            int row = in.nextInt();
            int seat = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
            sellSeatByNumber(seats, row, seat);

            printArray(seats);
            System.out.println();
        }
        else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("P"))
        {
           System.out.print("Enter price of seat desired: ");
           int price = in.nextInt();
           System.out.println();
           sellSeatByPrice(seats, row, seat, price);

           printArray(seats);
           System.out.println();
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Thank you for choosing the ticket choice app.");
    System.out.println();
}

public static void printArray(int[][] currSeat)
{
    final int ROWS = 9;
    final int COLUMNS = 10;

    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(currSeat[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static int[][] sellSeatByNumber(int[][] seats, int row, int seat)
{
    if (row <= 0 || row > 9)
    {
        if (seat <= 0 || seat > 10)
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter a valid row and seat: ");
        }
    }
    if (seats[row][seat] == 0)
    {
        System.out.print("That seat is taken. Please select another seat: ");
    }
    else
    {
        seats[seats.length - row][seat - 1] = 0;
    }
    return seats;
}

public static int[][] sellSeatByPrice(int[][] seats, int row, int seat, int price)
{
    if (seats[row][seat] = price)
    {
        seats[seats.length - row][seat - 1] = 0;
    }
    return seats;
}
}
```

Comment: rather than having two functions for sellseatbyprice(), why not have just one function and pass price value as let say "-1" for the case where somebody chooses "S".

Comment: i'm not sure if i understand your comment completely..i have to have two methods though, one sellSeatByNumber and one sellSeatByPrice

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters seem fine - the internal logic and syntax is incorrect.

Since you're using `static` methods, and passing along the seat matrix, that is okay - but you have to check that the values being passed in are inside the bounds of your matrix - or you will get exceptions on them.

For instance, you don't check the bounds in `sellSeatByPrice()`.  You really should do that, or a bogus row/seat combination could blow your program up.

It's also the case that the comparison given is incorrect:

```
if (seats[row][seat] = price)
```

should really be

```
if (seats[row][seat] == price)
```

as `=` is *assignment*, and `==` is *primitive comparison*.

Furthermore, in `sellSeatByNumber()`, you can still run into issues since an out of bounds row/seat combo will still blow up.  You *do* check the bounds - kudos - but you don't return anything if they're outside of those bounds.  In all reality, an `IllegalArgumentException` should be raised if they're stepping out of bounds, or you can return the matrix unmodified (which may be more straightforward).

Comment: Wow, this was extremely helpful, thank you. There are two things I am having trouble with: when the user inputs a bogus row/seat in sellSeatByNumber() and the overall sellSeatByPrice().
I'll will get to work on the changes you suggested, though. Thanks again.

Comment: I am having trouble checking to see if the input is out of bounds..do i use a row.length and seat.length?

Comment: For arrays in Java, `seats.length` gives you the horizontal length, and `seats[row].length` gives you the vertical length.  It may be better to set these up as constants somewhere instead, so they can be referred to easier.  I've got other projects that need my attention, but consider - what must be true about a row-seat combo for it to be valid?